# Recurrence: T(n) = 3T(n/2) + n^2(lgn)

Tags: algorithm, recurrence

Here is the full question...

Analysis of recurrence trees. Find the nice nonrecursive function f (n) such that
T(n) = Θ( f (n)). Show your work: what is the number of levels, number of instances on each level, work of each instance and the total work on that level.

This is a homework question so I do not expect exact answers, but I would like some guidance because I have no idea where to start. Here is part a:

a) T(n) = 3T(n/2) + n^2(lgn)

I really have no idea where to begin.

Comment: lookup master theorem...

Comment: See videos from chapter 4 here: https://class.coursera.org/algo-004/lecture

Answer (score 1):

These types of recurrences are solved with [Master's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem)

In your case `a=3`, `b=2` and therefore `c = log2(3) < 2`.

So you are in the third case and your complexity is `O(n^2 * log(n))`

Comment: I've looked at masters theorem. But we need the number of levels, instances and total work per level. Don't you need a tree method to do this?